# Laravel 5 ErrorException in LengthAwarePaginator.php

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

I'm creating my own custom pagination manually in Laravel 5 using `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` and `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`. It is working perfectly fine not until I added a constructor on my controller. Even just a blank constructor will return an error.

```
use App\Controllers\CoreController;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class CodeTables extends CoreController {

    public function __construct()
    {
       // nothing here, just blank
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $pagination = new LengthAwarePaginator($contents, $totalRows, $rowsPerPage, Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(), array('path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()));
    }

}
```

When I have that constructor, it gives me an error of:
`ErrorException in LengthAwarePaginator.php line 47: Division by zero`

But removing the constructor method works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that everything is working when you don't have constructor defined  in your `CodeTables` class, you should call parent constructor in your constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
   // nothing here, just blank
  parent::__construct();
}
```